# SQL dump uploading syntax error

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a sql dump

```
CREATE TABLE "documents" (
  "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  "create_ts" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  "update_ts" timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
  "number" int(11)  NOT NULL,
  "entity_id" int(11)  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO 'documents' VALUES (1,'2015-01-05 11:00:21',NULL,7036691,2709001);

CREATE TABLE "payments" (
  "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  "create_ts" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  "update_ts" timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
  "amount" decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  "finish_time" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
);

INSERT INTO "payments" VALUES (2709001,'2015-01-05 11:00:21',NULL,1000.00,'2015-01-04 21:00:00');
```

But when I'm trying to upload It via tools like phpmyadmin or navicat I'm getting an error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''documents' VALUES (1,'2015-01-05
>   11:00:21',NULL,7036691,2709001)' at line 1

What can be wrong ?

Comment: MySQL uses back.ticks for delimited identifiers. (Those `"`'s are ANSI SQL.)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with mySQL, but if it works comparable to sql-server; you are trying to insert `1` into an autoincrement attribute. You'll either have to disable autoincrement, or not insert a value for `id` (in which case you'll have to mention the attributes you _are_ inserting).

Comment: I am not sure try this INSERT INTO documents VALUES (1,'2015-01-05 11:00:21',NULL,7036691,2709001);. Remove quotes for table name. You are using single quotes for documents ant double quotes for payments check is that syntax is right.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the double quotes & single quotes from Table_name and Column_Names. In MySql `AUTOINCREMENT` does not exist, it must be 'AUTO_INCREMENT'. Besides default value for `timestamp` seems to be invalid.